# Designing notification sections in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I am trying to design a notification section for my ASP.NET website. 
My requirement is similar to  [this image layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh3RE.jpg). 
I was able to implement this with the asp repeater control and binding it with database.
I have table in my DB that has image, name and comments as its columns.
So according to the no. of rows in the DB table, the repeater control will get me the contents in the defined layout.

But i also wanted to implement the close button ("X" - top right corner). this close button will just remove the particular comment (but it will not delete data in DB).
Could you please help me in achieving this ??
Also thanks to suggest any other possible option to acheive this.
PFB the code i have done so far

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td style="height:64px;width:64px">
  <asp:Image  ID="imgEmployee" CssClass="imgClass" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath")%>'runat="server" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
  <p> <%# Eval("Comments")%></p>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

and code behind

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    DataSet ds = GetData();
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
  }
  private DataSet GetData()
  {
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblNotification", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
  }
```

And my table (tblNotification) has 3 columns - "ImagePath", "Name" and "Comments"

Comment: please share your codes you have tried so far.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim , I have added my code. thanks in advance for you reply.

Comment: You need to save the Close action in the database so you won't show that notification for the one who saw it. So you need an extra table tblUserNotification(UserId, NotificationId, Seen (bit1)) where you store the Seen status of that notification per logged in user.

Comment: @AdrianIftode- thanks for the feedback, So u mean to say, i will have to hit the database for close action and load the repeater control again with data where seen bit is 0.